# How to set the pagename equal to the category name in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I'm working on a project where I need to display a set of products on a page that are within a certain category of those products. I am establishing these categories by using the actual "Categories" functionality found in Wordpress. Then the plan is to create the actual products themselves as "Posts" that will be output put into a specific format. I will assign each product (post) to a category that I have created and chosen.

The problem is that I will have several different pages of categories, and those pages need to call the specific categories that I assign to those pages.  So I'm thinking that I could create a condition in my template that determines whether or not the "Pagename" is equal to "Categoryname". Then if the condition is true, I would tell Wordpress to display the posts in the category that is output.

This is very difficult for me to wrap my mind around.  I have successfully been able to get the pagename and the category name as a string, shown below.  But I don't know how to create a way to set them equal to each other, then display the posts in the category that is output.

```
<?php
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
   if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$pagename = $post->post_name;
echo $pagename;
}


rewind_posts();

$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("cat=&showposts=10&paged=$page");

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

               $category = get_the_category(); 
                                  if($category[0]){
                                  echo '<p>'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</p>';
                                                  }

               get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile; 
    simplemarket_pagination();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just use the category.php template?

I'm not sure I understand the need for having these be on *Pages* rather than *Category Pages*, per se.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I did think of that at one time, maybe I just was confused b/c I need to display a single post (product) inside of a box, instead of in blog format.